# How to create object within nested serializer on API create call

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an API with nested serializers where I overwrote the create method. My nested serializer has Foreign Keys to another model. Now I want to create objects of this other model in the same API call. This is where I am stuck.

My data looks like so:

```
[
    {
        "project": "project1",
        "name": "Graph1",
        "description": "testdescription",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "target1",
                "graph": 49
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Node1",
                "graph": 49
            }
        ],
        "edges": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Edge1",
                "graph": 49,
                "source": 15,
                "target": 16
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The fields `source` and `target` are Foreign Keys to the model Node.

Now, I can send this data without a problem when the fields `source` and `target` are already existent in the database.

But what I want is, that I send the data and I create a new Node object (source) and a new Node object (target) in the same call.

So far I overwrote the create method to enable nested serialization like so:

```
class GraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    nodes = NodeSerializer(many=True)
    edges = EdgeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:

        model   = Graph
        fields  = ('project',
                   'name',
                   'description',
                   'nodes',
                   'edges',
                   )


    def create(self, validated_data):
        nodes_data = validated_data.pop('nodes')
        edges_data = validated_data.pop('edges')
        graph = Graph.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for node_data in nodes_data:
            Node.objects.create(graph=graph,**node_data)

        for edge_data in edges_data:
            Edge.objects.create(graph=graph, **edge_data)

        return graph
```

that works, but like I said I need to create the node objects within the edges with the same call. Is there any way to do this? I can't find any sources online on how to do this.

Any help is very very much appreciated! Thanks so much!

```
My models

class Graph(models.Model):
    project         = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return self.node_set.all()


    @property
    def edges(self):
        return self.edge_set.all()

class Node(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    graph           = models.ForeignKey(Graph, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Edge(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    graph           = models.ForeignKey(Graph, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source          = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='source_set')
    target          = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='target_set')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: thanks ans2human. I think this is exactly what I am doing in the create method I posted. Which works, I can create ```edges```. Yet these edges have ```source```and ```target``` which are of type Node.  Basically I want to create these objects on an even deeper level. Am I clear or is that confusing?

Comment: Yes while creating `edges` you can post nested data which is pointed to `node`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the custom functionality by [**WritableNestedSerializers**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). By default nested serializers are used for `read-only` but in order to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved. So yes it can be done.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

Another way is to use [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) package. Here you create the parent serializers and refer them in the serializer where the relation is required. Only the difference is Update/Create methods are defined in the package which you'll have to write by yourself in above method.

For example, for the following model structure:

`Models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Site(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class AccessKey(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Profile(models.Model):
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    access_key = models.ForeignKey(AccessKey, null=True)


class Avatar(models.Model):
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='avatars')
```

`serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer


class AvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Avatar
        fields = ('pk', 'image',)


class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('pk', 'url',)


class AccessKeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AccessKey
        fields = ('pk', 'key',)


class ProfileSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    # Direct ManyToMany relation
    sites = SiteSerializer(many=True)

    # Reverse FK relation
    avatars = AvatarSerializer(many=True)

    # Direct FK relation
    access_key = AccessKeySerializer(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('pk', 'sites', 'avatars', 'access_key',)


class UserSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    # Reverse OneToOne relation
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'profile', 'username',)
```

Comment: thank you ans2human. I heard about this package before somewhere but was hoping to solve it without extra packages. But I will try and have a look at this and get back here and let you know. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Or is there a simple way of doing this without the package?

Comment: Yes, you can do this without the package too. Just need to define your own `Create/Update/..` methods.

Comment: thanks ans2human, I appreciate your help. But please read my question carefully. What you are describing from the docs is what I am already doing! And it works. But I am trying to create another object within the nested serializer. Like I said in my question I overwrote the create method like in the docs. Now, each object of the nested edge_set refers two Node objects as Foreign Keys. These two Node objects I want to create in the same call. And I hope to do so without more dependencies

Comment: Okay you wish to create 2 node objects in the same call. Okay as far as i can formulate right now is that you will need to create 2 node variable pointing to `NodeSerializers.` something like `node1` and `node2` and then poping the data for the respective node can be saved. Let me work on this and get back to you.

Comment: yes correct, I need to somehow create 2 nodes (source and target being their foreign key relation). Thank you, very much appreciated!